# Can I use the current URL in Firebase security rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have made a website that generates a unique URL (something.com/id1234 or something.com?id=id1234) when data is stored in a Firebase db. This URL can then be shared among users without the need for authentication. What I would like is something like this - in concept at least:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "stuff": {
      "$generated_id": {
          ".write": "urlParam.id === $generated_id",
          ".read": "urlParam.id === $generated_id"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

**Is it possible to somehow create security rules that only allow accessing the data that is stored in "current URL"? Or would this kind of access always require user authentication (which I very much would like to avoid)?**

I've searched around and looked through the documentation but can't find anything matching this scenario.